# history replace redirecting to project host url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, history.js

In my reactjs App [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#readme) npm package is used and I found a pre-written code `history.replace('/')` which is resulting in page redirection to hostname url of website.

Also when I open my webpage in google webcache it then gives error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState'
on 'History': A history state object with URL
'https://websiteurl.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin
'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com' and URL
'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:X4dz2ukZZAYJ:https://websiteurl.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in'
```

I have not used history api before, so i am not able to understand this behavior even after searching on internet.

Can someone explain this behavior?